# :exe moves cursor to first line of buffer

Tags: cursor-motions, functions

```
function! DebugC()
    let l:debugStr = "printf(\"" . s:debugPrefixStr . s:debugCounter . "\");"

    if g:debugstringAlwaysIncludeHeader
        let l:incStr = "#include <stdio.h>; "
        let l:debugStr = l:incStr . l:debugStr
    endif

    :put=l:debugStr
endfunc " }}}
```

Method dumps the text correctly but if I use execute instead of call, it always moves the cursor to the top of the

```
" doesn't move to top of file
autocmd Filetype c,cpp nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <Plug>DumpDebugString  :call DebugC()<CR>

" moves cursor to the top of the file
autocmd Filetype c,cpp nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <Plug>DumpDebugString  :exe DebugC()<CR>
```

Adding `getcurpos()`, `setpos()` at the start and end of the function doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In vim, a function which does not explicitly return a value actually returns 0.  So, your code is equivalent to `exe 0`, which is like `:0` meaning move the cursor to the first line.

Comment: Wow, so troublesome, yet so simple of an explanation!

So I get I can solve it just by `return getcurpos()[1] + 1` or something like that..

Do you think  there is a more elegant solution to the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `exe` instead of `call`?  It is not clear from your question why `call` doesn't work.  And you can just return empty string `''`, `exe ''` should do nothing.

Comment: The actual call is a little more complicated, something like this:

`autocmd Filetype c,cpp nnoremap      <buffer> <silent> <Plug>DumpDebugString  :<C-U>exe <SID>debugFunctionWrapper("s:debugC")<CR>`

You're right on the second remark though, returning `' '` does the job...

Comment: You can use `call` in that example.  Actually, `:<c-u>call s:function()<cr>` works too.  But, the alternative solution, if required, is just return empty string `return ''` in `debugFunctionWrapper`.

Comment: Ah, yeah you're right again.. `call` does work in this case as well..

Thanks again!